# I want to share my VPN internet to other devices on Windows 11 (without `Hosted Network Supported`)(Newer generation modules)

Tags: wireless-networking, hotspot, internet-sharing, wireless-hotspot, mobile-hotspot

I wish to share my internet over my Laptop PC. Currently, we use ISP to connect to the internet, then we use VPN/Proxy to access the global network.

The Issue I have is on the old time, I would use a VPN/Proxy per device, and as the prices raised so high because of user access limitations in my country, previously I would use a good VPN on my Windows devices, then re-shared it to my other devices; and I would use the `netsh` ad-hoc command...
configure netsh and then `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`

But It seems new devices WiFi drivers does not support that. But still, Windows provide another `Mobile Hotspot` feature,... and with it the issue is...

It is available if I connect to no VPN network, saying it can share WiFi over to WiFi.
But once I connect to a VPN network, the whole panel becomes disabled.

So:

1. I'm wondering now, how I can still share my VPN with other devices
2. Should I swap my WiFi module? Are there any modules among the new ones, which also are newer that support `ad-hoc` (Hosted Network Supported: Yes) too?
3. should I get an external WiFi device, and not lose my current system WiFi card?
4. Is SoftAP destined to do these things too? should I keep my current module? in case I need to change it to an older one? or are there any new one with Hosted Network Support

Current module: Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9260 160MHz

Comment: The simplest would be to setup the VPN in the router, if supported.

Comment: Unfortunately, my company only provides SoftEther. and they have another network that is both metered and slower, but also that one used a very customized version of the certificate that Mikrotik support said we see weird flags in the certificate, that are not supported by our devices. So, I use router to access wan, also spread it through WiFi for normal usage; then to PC, PC Connects to Server, Share Over WiFi HostedNetwork(AdHoc), And again goes back to Router, and Router also spread the Tunneled network.
But I also want to do the same using my laptop, as I did it in my friend's older one.